# SQLAlchemy: How to save an object with the foreign key?

Tags: foreign-keys, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I've got these classes.

```
class User(object):

    query = db_session.query_property()        

    def __init__(self, username, passhash, salt):    
        self.username = username    
        self.passhash = passhash    
        self.salt = salt

users = Table('users', metadata,    
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),    
    Column('username', String(60)),    
    Column('passhash', String),    
    Column('salt', String)    
    )

mapper(User, users)

class Buoy(object):

    query = db_session.query_property()    
    author = relationship("User", backref=backref("buoys", order_by=id))

    def __init__(self, label, lead, body, author):    
        self.label = label    
        self.lead = lead    
        self.body = body    
        self.author = author

buoys = Table('buoys', metadata,    
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),    
    Column('label', String),    
    Column('lead', String),    
    Column('body', String),    
    Column('author_id', Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))    
    )

mapper(Buoy, buoys)
```

In my Python Flask code I would like to create and save a new buoy:

```
buoy = Buoy(label, lead, body, current_user)
```

When I do it this way, the buoy.author is correct but buoy.author_id is None. Please, is any way how to automatically assign current_user.id to the buoy.author_id when buoy.author is known?

Answer (score 3):

`buoy.author_id` will be set after `buoy` instance is added to a session and `session.flush()` is called.

Comment: buoy = Buoy(label, lead, body, current_user) db_session.add(buoy) db_session.commit() where db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=True, bind=engine)) and it still does not work :( I mean there is no value in author_id column in my database.

Comment: is the `author` also added to a session (and commited)?

Answer (score 0):

This results from the author object not being present in the database
saving the author before the `Buoy` object would solve it.

seeing I'm coming from a completely different decade, sqlalchemy may versions differ.

```py
with db_session:
   author = User(***)
   db_session.add(author)
   db_session.commit()

with db_session:
   buoy = Buoy(***)
   db_session.add(buoy)
   db_session.commit()
```